# how to pull in value of datetime field from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below input fields and I am trying to pull in the datetime from start_date and end_date from my database.  however when I do the code as shown below it just pulls in blank dates.  I checked the values of the `$start_date` and `$end_date` and they are valid.  Please let me know what could be wrong.

```
echo 'Start Date:'
    , '<input id="evfinal" type="datetime-local" name="sdate" value="' . $row['start_date'] . '" />'
    , 'End Date:','<input id="evfinal" type="datetime-local" name="edate" value="' . $row['end_date'] . '" />';
```

code to pull data:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM events a INNER JOIN (SELECT id_user, MAX(event_id) as maxID FROM events GROUP BY id_user) b ON a.id_user = b.id_user AND a.event_id = b.maxID WHERE a.id_user = '25'")
or die(mysql_error()); 


// store the record of the "example" table into $row
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: post the code you use to pull the data from the database.

Comment: "the values of the $start_date and $end_date" then why aren't you using those instead of `$row`?

Comment: edited to include code to pull data

Comment: Is there more code? Inside that while loop is where the important stuff is.

Comment: @NicholasPickering no just the echo of the fields.  but i guess my main question is im wondering if there is a special way to pull datetime fields and display them? i cant make it a text input to display it because I am allowing edits of the date in this form

Comment: This does not answer your question, but isn't your query the same as `SELECT * FROM events WHERE id_user=25 ORDER BY event_id DESC LIMIT 1;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try  this way: `value="<?php echo $row['start_date']; ?>"`
Avoid printing static html codes with php as possible as.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.